# Using glibmm / c++, do I really need to worry about refcounting?

Tags: c++, glibmm

I am new to glibmm and am looking at the documentation for Glib::TimeZone c++ class. There are a few places, eg,. `Glib::TimeZone::create_utc()` where it states:

"You should release the return value by calling g_time_zone_unref() when you are done with it."

This seems odd for a C++ class.

Looking in the source code for the destructor of Glib::TimeZone, `g_time_zone_unref()` is called there, so am I right in thinking that I should ignore the statement in the documentation?

It seems a lot of the documentation refers to glib rather than glibmm, as if it's been generated from the underlying glib docs. Is this so? Should I be taking all the docs with a pinch of salt?

I'm using glibmm-2.68

Comment: This is a fair question. I think _"You should release the return value by calling g_time_zone_unref() when you are done with it."_ is a leftover from when bringing in the C documentation. The class _should_ manage its own resources. It even has a user-defined destructor (`Glib::TimeZone::~TimeZone()  noexcept`). Try compiling with `-g -fsanitize=leak` and if it doesn't report any leaks, write a trouble report on glibmm about that sentense - or make a pull request where you correct it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is sort of explained in the source code: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glibmm/-/blob/master/glib/src/timezone.hg#L54-61

```
  // GTimeZone is refcounted, but Glib::TimeZone is not.
  // GTimeZone is immutable. Therefore, there is no problem having several
  // Glib::TimeZone instances wrap the same GTimeZone, and it's easier to use
  // Glib::TimeZone without Glib::RefPtr.
  _CLASS_BOXEDTYPE(TimeZone, GTimeZone, NONE, g_time_zone_ref, g_time_zone_unref, GLIBMM_API)
  _IGNORE(g_time_zone_ref, g_time_zone_unref)
```

So `g_time_zone_ref()` and `g_time_zone_unref()` are called automatically by the C++ `Glib::TimeZone` class.  You should not call them explicitly.

The source code also says `create()` is deprecated and you should use `create_identifier()` instead.  The difference is that `create()` returns the UTC zone if parsing failed, which makes it impossible to know if parsing failed, while `create_identifier()` returns null on error.

Why does the online documentation mention `g_time_zone_unref()`?  Because it is auto-generated from the C documentation and the generator is not smart enough.  An object lesson about the perils of generated documentation.

Comment: Great. As I suspected, thanks for clarifying.